# Parse error: syntax error after inputting API info and tokens

Tags: php, api, token

After updating the web app with Instagram and twitter client id, secret and tokens,

I encountered  parser and syntax error on line 1 of the following script. I suspect there is a PHP version conflict. How do I fixe this? Thanks.

```
function stream_for($resource = '', array $options = [])
{
if (is_scalar($resource)) {
    $stream = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
    if ($resource !== '') {
        fwrite($stream, $resource);
        fseek($stream, 0);
    }
    return new Stream($stream, $options);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your function should be

```
function stream_for($resource = '', $options = array()){
//rest here
}
```

but yours is valid for 5.4.0+ (Released: 01 March 2012)

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. So looks like I would need to manually update the syntax for all the scripts of this web app... I am not a PHP guy, just picking up this for an one time assignment.